# Wampserver refused to connect with wordpress when accessing mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp, wampserver

I can access my localhost using a computer, and I can access it too via my mobile phone, but when I installed wordpress on it, I can no longer access it via mobile phone, it's always telling me "localhost refused to connect" with error code ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED but it works completely fine on my computer. I tried removing the .htaccess but no luck. However, I can access html files for example the readme.html (on phone http://192.168.0.13/readme.html)

My current IPv4 Address on my computer is 192.168.0.13, and I use this address to access it on my phone, but it always redirects me to "localhost". Is it because the home url of my wordpress is set to "http://localhost"? How can I fix this?

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf (if it helps)

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.0.1
    Require ip 192.168.0.28
    Require ip 192.168.0.33
    Require ip 192.168.0.13
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using WampServer Version 3.1.0 64bit and here are my configurations

```
Apache 2.4.27
PHP 7.1.9
MySQL 5.7.19
MariaDB 10.2.8
```

What am I missing? I badly need it to work, it's for my web development purposes.

Comment: Can you see what PHP is saying in the error logs?

Comment: Hi, I only got 5 entries in my error log, nothing serious and it's unrelated.

Comment: It is possible that your Wordpress installation is configured with a MySQL account that can only be accessed from the localhost. Go to your mysql database and in the host column enter %.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because the home url of my wordpress is set to "http://localhost"?

Yes, it probably is. If you are being redirected to localhost constantly. You can access a HTML file because it does not containt the logic of the Wordpress PHP installation which will try to redirect you to the base URL. Try changing the base URL of your wordpress installation in the admin panel on your computer (if that is possible) otherwise you should change the base url in the `wp-config.php` file.

Try changing it to your local IPv4 address: http://192.168.0.13

This can probably help you: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Also for your apache configuration try this:

```
ServerName 192.168.0.13
ServerAlias localhost
```

I do not have any real experience with Apache but as far as i understood the documentation this should work for you.
Sources:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias

Answer (score 0):

Jeez, I tried changing both wordpress address and site address to my local ipv4 address 192.168.0.13, and voila, I can finally accessed it. Lol

I'm so dumb, Thank you for the help guys.